# angularjs - mousedown & moving over elements while mouse down event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

To explain what I am trying to do I have created an example where you can play with:

http://plnkr.co/edit/usrmiNkj5YJY5SlV8ETw?p=preview

I want to draw multiple tiles green while my mouse is down.
This:

```
<div ng-mousedown="drawImage($parent.$index,$index)"></div>
```

works only when the mouse is going down on the element not outside.

Is there an way to check if the mouse is already down and draw the tiles green?

Please use the code I made to create an working example.

Comment: Don't do it with angular `ngWhatever`. Write your custom directive to handle onmouseover, onmousedown, etc events.

Comment: @dfsq Can you create an working example?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to include a few more event handlers, for mouseup and mousemove, like this

```
<div class="tile" ng-repeat="x in y track by $index" ng-class="x" ng-mouseup="removeFlag()" ng-mousedown="setFlag($parent.$index,$index)" ng-mousemove="drawImage($parent.$index,$index)"></div>
```

Then add the functions

```
$scope.drawImage = function(y,x){
  if ($scope.mouseIsDown)
    $scope.map[y][x] = "green";
}

$scope.setFlag = function(y,x){
   $scope.mouseIsDown = true;
   this.drawImage(y,x)
}

$scope.removeFlag = function(){
   $scope.mouseIsDown = false;
}
```

This sets a flag when the mouse is down, and sets the color when the cursor moves over an element *and* the mouse is down.

[**PLNKR**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RsekFggBBQiljvqs3Vd1?p=preview)

Comment: This is what I thought too until mousedown was occured outside the tiles. So when I move with mouseup it will draw green. You're close

Comment: @Ismail - You mean like this -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/S0K7ZvY9aukKOedF3GtJ?p=preview**

Comment: @adeno still close haha, when you're out of the body (140 pixels down) and do mouseup it will stil not work. With jquery you could append it to the document what will probably fix it.

Comment: You can attach the event handlers to the document, but not sure it would help much -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/bXUTR1f7BPzajmm350mT?p=preview**